# Adding CSS style with jquery has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to check in the AJAX call if length of the response variable is bigger then 1.
If that is true I need to add this style to my footer:

```
success: function(response) {
    for (var i = 0, len = response.results.length; i < len; i++) 
        {
            if(response.results.length>1)
            {
               $("#footer").css("position:relative");
            }
        }....
}
```

This is my predefined style in my css file:

```
#footer
    {
        z-index:11;
        bottom:0;
        position: fixed;
        float: left;
        width:100%;
        height:30px;
        background-color:black;
    }
```

I did some debugging and everything is working as it should be working but my footer element still has `position:fixed`

What am I doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#footer").css("position", "relative");
```

or:

```
$("#footer").css({ position: "relative" });
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of .css() is wrong. It is:

```
$('#element').css('property', 'value');
```

Take a look at the **[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.getElementById('footer').style.position ='relative';
```